# Spring Security: Why is my custom AccessDecisionVoter not invoked

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-java-config

I'm trying to do URL authorization using a custom `AccessDecisionVoter`. I don't get any errors and debugging shows that my voter is picked up at start up. However, at runtime, the `vote` method is not called, thus allowing every authenticated user full access.

Note that, I don't need method security. I'm also not using XML config. That rules out every example ever posted on the internet regarding this topic.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
@Order(-10)
public class HttpSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Value("${trusted_ports}")
    private List<Integer> trustedPorts;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private ServiceIdAwareVoter serviceIdAwareVoter;

    RequestMatcher requestMatcher = new OrRequestMatcher(
        // @formatter:off
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**", GET.name()),
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**", POST.name()), 
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**", DELETE.name()),
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**", PATCH.name()), 
        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**", PUT.name())
        // @formatter:on
    );

    @Override
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(preAuthProvider());
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.
            httpBasic().and().
            authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().
            accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager()).and().
            csrf().disable().
            logout().disable().
            exceptionHandling().and().
            sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS).and().
            anonymous().disable().
            addFilterAfter(preAuthFilter(), X509AuthenticationFilter.class).
            addFilter(authFilter());
        // @formatter:on
    }

    AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        return new UnanimousBased(ImmutableList.of(serviceIdAwareVoter));
    }

    Filter preAuthFilter() throws Exception {
        PreAuthenticationFilter preAuthFilter = new PreAuthenticationFilter(trustedPorts);

        preAuthFilter.setAuthenticationManager(super.authenticationManager());

        return preAuthFilter;
    }

    PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preAuthProvider() {
        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preAuthProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
        UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> userDetailsServiceWrapper = new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<>();

        userDetailsServiceWrapper.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());

        preAuthProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceWrapper);

        return preAuthProvider;
    }

    Filter authFilter() throws Exception {
        AppIdAppKeyAuthenticationFilter authFilter = new AppIdAppKeyAuthenticationFilter(requestMatcher);
        authFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new ExceptionStoringAuthenticationFailureHandler());
        authFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new UrlForwardingAuthenticationSuccessHandler());

        authFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());

        return authFilter;
    }

    AuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        AppIdAppKeyAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new AppIdAppKeyAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());

        return authProvider;
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Background:**

After hours of debugging, I found out the root cause of the problem, which is really deep. Part of it is due to the fact that the Spring Security Java config is very poorly documented (for which I've opened a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-3188)). Theirs, as well as most online, examples are copy-pasted from XML config whereas the world has stopped using Spring XML config since probably 2010. Another part is due to the fact that REST service security is an afterthought in the Spring Security design and they don't have first-class support for protecting applications that don't have a login page, error page and the usual view layer. Last but not the least is that there were several (mis)configurations in my app which all came together and created a perfect storm of mind-boggling complexity.

**Technical Context:**

Using the `authorizeRequests()` configures a `ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer` which ultimately sets up a `UnanimousBased` `AccessDecisionManager` with a `WebExpressionVoter`. This `AccessDecisionManager` is called from the `FilterSecurityInterceptor` if the authentication succeeds (obviously there's no point in authorization if the user fails authentication in the first place).

**Issues:**

- In my `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer` subclass, which is basically the Java version of the `web.xml`, I'd configured filters not to intercept forward requests. I'm not going to go into the *why* here. For the interested, here's an example of how it's done:

  ```
  private Dynamic registerCorsFilter(ServletContext ctx) {
      Dynamic registration = ctx.addFilter("CorsFilter", CorsFilter.class);

      registration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(getDispatcherTypes(), false, "/*");    
      return registration;
  }

  private EnumSet<DispatcherType> getDispatcherTypes() {
      return (isAsyncSupported() ? EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.ASYNC)
    : EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.INCLUDE));
  }
  ```

If you take the `DispatcherType.FORWARD` out of the dispatcher types set, the registered filter doesn't kick in for that kind of request.

- The `authFilter` shown in my question extended from `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and had an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` which forwarded the request to the destination URL after successful authentication. The default Spring implementation uses a `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` which does a redirect to a webpage, which is unwanted in the context of a REST app.
- Due to the above 2 reasons, the `FilterSecurityInterceptor` was not invoked after successful authentication which in turn, skipped the authorization chain causing the issue in my original post.

**Fix:**

- Get rid of custom dispatcher configuration from web app initializer.
- Don't do forward, or redirect, from `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`. Just let the request take it's natural course.
- The custom voter has a `vote` method that looks as follows:

  ```
  public int vote(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation fi,
          Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
  }
  ```

The `attributes` in my case, as shown in my original post, is the string expression `fullyAuthenticated`. I didn't use it for authorization as I already knew the user to have been authenticated through the various filters in the authentication flow.

I hope this serves as documentation for all those souls who're suffering from the lack of documentation in Spring Security Java config.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I have separate Auth server and Resource server. When resource server is calling oauth/check_token for authentication and authorization of client and token, it is not calling my custom voter. how to solve this? I am new to spring security and i faced some problem in understanding your answer. Can you Please explain how to add custom voter in AUTH SERVER ?

Comment: @SameerSharma Start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Your config is saying that you are allowing access to fully authenticated users right here:

```
authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().
```

You are telling Spring Security to grant access to any request as long as they are fully authenticated. What's you're goal? How are you trying to restrict access, by a role/permission? I'm guessing it's something that you are dictating inside your custom voter bean?

Usually the voter bean comes into play when you have conflicting security levels, for example, here you say that that all requests have full access but if your code hits a method with method level security like this (not a very real-world example):

```
@PreAuthrorize("permitNone")
public void someMethod{
   ...
}
```

You're going to have voters come into play because your java security config is saying "grant access to everyone" (voting yes to access) but this method annotation is "grant access to no one" (voting no to access).

In your case, there's nothing to vote on, you are granting everyone access.

Comment: The way I understand it, `fullyAuthenticated` is for authentication and voters are for authorization. I need all users to be fully authenticated before they're allowed to access the any resource. Once they've been **successfully authenticated**, I then want to voters to decide whether they've access to the resource they're requesting for. 2 completely separate concerns at play.

Comment: Okay, I am thinking if you gave all your authenticated users a role, you'd hit your role voter. You could have a role called "isAuthenticated" and change your config to read:

_authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("isAuthenticated")._
or if there's an a generic "user" role, you could do:  
 _authorizeRequests().anyRequest().access("isAuthenticated() and hasRole('user'")._
at this point your config is indicating that authorization functionality will need to take place.

Comment: You're missing the point. If I could hard-code the roles at compile time, I'd not need a custom voter. I need the access decision to be dynamically made, not glued in the config.

Comment: No I'm suggesting adding a new generic role on top of whatever secret sauce is happening in your voter in order to initiate the authorization process. That is your problem, your security config is bypassing authorization checks altogether, so I'm giving examples of how you could kick start it. You can probably enable debug and watch what the filter chain is doing at each step to get a better idea